# How to submit a form with specific fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have a form like this:

```
<form name="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" action="/submit.jsp" method="post">
    <fieldset id="ccData">
        <input id="ccNumber" name="ccNumber"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="otherData">
        <input id="requestId" name="requestId"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When you slick submit, I would like to submit(via ajax) only #ccData filedset to some different url (e.g. submitCC.jsp) and based on response I want to submit full form to actual url.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: your question is very general, so here is a very general answer: use javascript/ajax.

Comment: @undefined Only thing I tried was removing one fieldset and then submitting the form. Which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method

```
var formData = $("#ccData").serialize()​;
$.post("TheUrl",formData);
```

Comment: serialize will not work for uploading the files. what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with JavaScript - e.g jQuery. You build an eventHandler like

```
$('#paymentForm').on('click', function () {
  $(this).preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('first_send')) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "your_url",
      data: { ccData: $('#ccData').val()}
    }).done(function ( data ) {
      $('#paymentForm').addClass('first_send')
      // examin the data, insert stuff you need and send the form again
      // with ajax
    })
  } else {
   $(this).removeClass('first_send')
   // this is the second send - so do stuff here - show a result or so
  }
})
```

With the class first_send you can check if it is the first send or the second. This is just an untested, incomplete idea how you could do it. I guess you get the big picture ...

Comment: `else` will never occur since you haven't prevented form from submitting through browser default. Would also require user click submit twice

Comment: @charlietfl you are right! As I wrote - it's incomplete. I just wanted to give an idea how it "could" be implemented. Thanks anyways for the comment!

Comment: would make more sense to edit solution so OP has better chance of the code working